# Combine two select statements grouped by date returning two columns of data

Tags: mysql

This seems like an easy task but my basic sql knowledge is failing me as I'm still learning.

Basically, I'm trying to combine:

```
SELECT DATE(created) DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT created) newpost FROM surveys
WHERE created >= Last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
AND created < last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY DATE(created);
```

and

```
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP) DATE,subs FROM trafficstats
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
AND TIMESTAMP < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

into one query that will return data, grouped by date, into two additional columns - `newposts` and `subs`.

I've tried using `UNION`, which doesn't seem to be giving me the output I want. It combined the data into one column (`newpost`), and also didn't group by date.

I'm still fairly new to writing `MySQL` queries, and I've tried searching for answers to no avail. Hoping to seek the knowledge of those smarter than me here.

Comment: Can you please create a simple minimal dataview of what you have and what you expect of the results? Because as you mentioned these two queries have 1 common field `DATE` and two different fields `newpost` and `subs`. So if you combine these two queries, does it mean that records from the first query will all have empty `subs` field and records from second query will all have empty `newpost` filed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use JOIN

```
    select t1.DATE, t1.newpost, t2.subs 
    from (
      SELECT DATE(created) DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT created) newpost 
      FROM surveys 
      WHERE created >= Last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
      AND created < last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
      GROUP BY DATE(created)
    ) t1
    left join  (
      SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP) DATE, subs 
      FROM trafficstats 
      WHERE TIMESTAMP >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
      AND TIMESTAMP < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ) t2 on t1.DATE = t2.DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want one row per distinct date, with two different count values shown.

This kind of query is slightly tricker than it seems at first glance, because the two summary queries might have different sets of dates.

So you need to start with a subquery that yields all possible dates of interest. You then need to LEFT JOIN each summary query to it. You must use LEFT JOIN instead of the ordinary inner JOIN, because LEFT JOIN doesn't suppress rows from the right side of the join when they don't match any rows from the left side.

Here goes:

All your dates. Notice the `UNION` operation is a setwise (duplicate-removing) union operation.

```
            SELECT DISTINCT DATE(created) DATE FROM newpost
             WHERE created >= Last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
              AND created < last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
             UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT DATE(TIMESTAMP) DATE FROM trafficstats 
             WHERE TIMESTAMP >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
               AND TIMESTAMP < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Then you need your two summary subqueries. The first one is this. Notice that I changed `COUNT(DISTINCT created)` to `COUNT(*)` because I don't understand the logic behind the `DISTINCT` there. Can you have more than one row for a single post; do you tell them apart by timestamp? If you have a row for each post you should `COUNT(*)`.

```
           SELECT DATE(created), COUNT(*) newposts
             FROM newpost
            GROUP BY DATE(created)
```

The second summary is this. Again, I counted rows.

```
           SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP), COUNT(*) subs
             FROM trafficstats
            GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)
```

Finally, join those three subqueries like so. You get the dates from the first subquery, and the summary-by-date information from the second two subqueries.

```
     SELECT dates.DATE, posts.newposts, subs.subs
       FROM ( /* date subquery */ ) dates
       LEFT JOIN ( /* posts subquery */ ) posts ON dates.DATE = posts.DATE
       LEFT JOIN ( /* subs subquery */ ) subs ON dates.DATE = subs.DATE
      ORDER BY dates.DATE
```

Putting it all together:

```
     SELECT dates.DATE, posts.newposts, subs.subs
       FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT DATE(created) DATE FROM newpost
             WHERE created >= Last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
              AND created < last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
             UNION
            SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP) DATE FROM trafficstats 
             WHERE TIMESTAMP >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
               AND TIMESTAMP < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            ) dates
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT DATE(created), COUNT(*) newposts
                  FROM newpost
                 GROUP BY DATE(created)
            ) posts ON dates.DATE = posts.DATE
       LEFT JOIN (
                   SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP), COUNT(*) subs
                     FROM trafficstats
                    GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)
            ) subs ON dates.DATE = subs.DATE
      ORDER BY dates.DATE
```

Comment: The result I need is one row grouped by date, with a column for the new post count and a column for the subs count. The good news is that all of the dates match between the two tables so it shouldn't drop any data due to null values.